# Is photoshop elements enough to learn to develop using entire photoshop sdk?

Tags: image, plugins, image-processing, image-manipulation, photoshop

I spend a large amount of my time writing code dealing with images. I would like to pick up the photoshop SDK so I can write photoshop plugins to sell, but I don't own photoshop or photoshop elements. Is photoshop elements sufficient to buy in order to write photoshop plugins, and if so, how recent a version do I need? If I really need photoshop, not photoshop elements, how recent a version do I need?

As a side question is there a recommended reference for learning the Photoshop SDK?

Note: No I have no intention of selling untested code. But if I can learn the photoshop SDK writing for photoshop elements and evaluate what I came up with only having had to purchase elements that is better because I will risk a lot less money on something that might go nowhere. If after working with photoshop elements I come up with something nice enough that I really want to sell it for photoshop, then I can invest in the full photoshop to test with. But that only works if the photoshop SDK can be learned using photoshop elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to sell plugins for photoshop, there is no way you are going to do that without owning a copy of photoshop, unless you are planning to write code, compile it and than sell it without once testing or running it yourself. I have yet to meet the programmer who can sell their software without ever running it.

If you are going to develop plugins for PS elements, than elements will of course suffice.

As a sidenote, consider that photoshop sells for about $699. Just be realistic and know that you will make a loss unless you will get corporate customers.

Also be aware that there are already alot of plugins for photoshop and make sure your idea doesn't already exist, unless you are going to have the corporate connections to get it sold that they didn't...

To get back to realism, what I would do personally is get a "free" version of photoshop and develop your plugin. If it all works and it looks like you did a good enough job to earn more than $700 with this, go and buy a copy and test your plugin again. Then start selling it.

Answer (score 0):

No, You need the full version of PhotoShop. Check out the requirements here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop/sdk.html

No mention of PhotoShop Elements...

Comment: They're talking about how to make 64 bits plugins for CS5, which isn't the scope of the OP.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to develop plug-ins for PS Elements: here is one 
[site](http://www.thepowerxchange.com/photoshop_elements_plug_in_23_ctg.html) offering such plug-ins.

So it should be possible yes (*).

UPDATE: (*) but you may need to download an older version of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

You should make plugins for GIMP to help make the world a better place. And optionally sell those plugins. gimp.org :D

Answer (score 0):

If you are a student (in college) and/or still have an active student card/ID, just get the student version, which is the entire version but cheaper ;)  Then you can own both for a much cheaper pricetag.

That assumes you are a student though.